# Return utf-8 from XPath using lxml and requests

Tags: xpath, unicode, utf-8, lxml, python-requests

I'm trying to figure out if I'm using lxml's `xpath` function correctly. Here's my current code, including all the workarounds that we've slowly amassed in a pretty sizable scraping library that deals with terrible, **terrible** input:

```
import certifi, requests
from lxml import html
s = requests.session()
r = s.get(
    url,
    verify=certifi.where(),
    **request_dict
)

# Throw an error if a bad status code is returned.
r.raise_for_status()

# If the encoding is iso-8859-1, switch it to cp1252 (a superset)
if r.encoding == 'ISO-8859-1':
    r.encoding = 'cp1252'

# Grab the content
text = r.text
html_tree = html.fromstring(text)
```

So if this all works properly, `requests` uses `r.encoding` to decide how to create a unicode object when `r.text` is called. Great. We take that unicode object (`text`) and we send that into `ltml.html.fromstring()`, which recognizes that it's unicode, and gives us back an `ElementTree`.

That all seems to be working properly, but what's troubling is that when I then do:

```
html_tree.xpath('//text()')[0]
```

Which should give me the first text node in the tree, I get back a string, not a unicode object, and I find myself having to instead write:

```
html_tree.xpath('//text()')[0].decode('utf8')
```

**This sucks.**

The whole idea of all the work I did at the beginning was to create the [Mythical Unicode Sandwich](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#35), but no matter what I do, I get back binary strings. What am I missing here?

---

Here's a proof of concept for you:

```
import certifi, requests
from lxml import html
s = requests.session()
r = s.get('https://www.google.com', verify=certifi.where())
print type(r.text)  # <type 'unicode'>, GREAT!
html_tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
first_node = html_tree.xpath('//text()', smart_strings=False)[0]
print type(first_node)  # <type 'str'>, TERRIBLE!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, as so often happens, I found the answer shortly after posting a long, detailed question. The reason `lxml` returns byte strings even when you carefully give it unicode is because of [a performance optimization in `lxml`](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-does-lxml-sometimes-return-str-values-for-text-in-python-2). From the FAQ:

> In Python 2, lxml's API returns byte strings for plain ASCII text values, be it for tag names or text in Element content.
>
> The reasoning is that ASCII encoded byte strings are compatible with Unicode strings in Python 2, but consume less memory (usually by a factor of 2 or 4) and are faster to create because they do not require decoding. Plain ASCII string values are very common in XML, so this optimisation is generally worth it.

However in Python 3:

> lxml always returns Unicode strings for text and names, as does ElementTree. Since Python 3.3, Unicode strings containing only characters that can be encoded in ASCII or Latin-1 are generally as efficient as byte strings. In older versions of Python 3, the above mentioned drawbacks apply.

So there you have it. It's a performance optimization in lxml that adds to the confusion around byte and unicode strings.

At least it's fixed in Python 3! Time to upgrade.